# Sitecore package designer "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm running this local version of my Sitecore (Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 120706)) website and I have these CMS changes that I want to package up with the package designer. When I go to the package designer I get this error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +9
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +143
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Commands.Commands.Init() +63
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Commands.Commands' threw an
>   exception.]
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Commands.Commands.Init() +0
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +639    Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +110
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.CreateCodeBeside(String type)
>   +35    Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e) +114    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421    System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +189    Sitecore.Shell.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +197
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2098
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009

I tried to figure out what this error is, my log files don't really help me. I compared with my live site (which runs the package designer perfectly) and they are pretty much identical.

What should I look for to find the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a command referencing an assembly which is missing in your setup. Compare your local assemblies with the ones of your live site and check your */App_Config/Commands.config* for custom commands or references to custom assemblies.

Comment: When I compare these 2 files I see they are identical. I tried removing all of the commands and got the same results. I'll paste the content of that config file in my original post. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you also compare your bin folders... pretty sure theres an assembly missing

Comment: I can't post the full config, it's too big. But it looks all pretty kosher and the same config runs correctly online. Basically my whole App_Config folder is identical (ran it though BeyondCompare). The Bin folder is also pretty much identical, I have some differences: System.Net.Http.xml, System.Net.Http.dll, System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll, Newtonsoft.Json.xml, Newtonsoft.Json.dll, Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.xml, HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.dll and AjaxMin.dll. Do you think any of these could make a difference?

Comment: I moved each DLL one by one, it seems that my nuget packages updating my Newtonsoft.Json.dll caused the issue. I think I'll just stop using Nuget alltogether haha :) Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 1):

It is may be actually a combination of mismatched dll's and manifest entries while referencing.
It could be Newtonsoft.Json.dll as well.

Please go to web.config at root level of your app.

and under

```html
<dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

</runtime>
```

Fixes all